# How installshield searches and create jvm path hint file?

Tags: jvm, installshield

I'm using installshield to install a product, it will first read the is:javahome tag to specify and verify the jre position, if not set then read a tmp file /tmp/istemp2223070045253/xxx_linux_150.jvm to install with. Here is content of this jvm hint file:

```
DESC: IBM Java Runtime Environment (JRE) 1.5.0 for Linux
JVM_EXE: bin/java
SKIP_PATH_SEARCH: true
CLASSPATH: "-cp "
CLASSPATH_SEPARATOR: :
SYSTEM: "-D"
SYSTEM_SEPARATOR: =
INITIAL_HEAP_SIZE: "-Xms"
MAXIMUM_HEAP_SIZE: "-Xmx"
JVM_PROPERTIES:
"java.vendor=IBM..."
"java.version=1.5.0..."
/:
SET_ENV_FOR_WIZARD:
JAVA2D_USEAWTFONTS=0
/:
PATH_HINT:
was/linux/java
../linux
linux/java



/:
SEARCH_ALL: 0
JVM_HOME:/update/xxx/was/linux/java/
```

I want to know how this jvm file works and how the path_hint generated? Is there any doc that I can refer? Thanks